# PHP SOAP XML not working at all

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I need to create a `SOAP XML` schema to connect PHP to `SOAP Server`. I read about `SOAPClient` class in [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) but it's quite unclear how to actually create an `XML Schema` like the one I need. I've also read about `SOAPVar` but I'm not able to make it work, probably because it's the first time that I use `PHP SOAP`.
The function I'm calling from the server is named `insertContact` which requires a string `password` and a `Contact` object, where `source` and `emailAddress1` are the only mandatory fields.

Anyway, this should be the `XML` schema:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Header>
      <ns9:HeaderInfo xmlns:ns9="http://example.com/" xmlns:ns8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:ns7="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:ns6="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/FileServiceWcfServiceLibrary.Domain" xmlns:ns5="http://example.com.Utilities" xmlns:ns4="http://example.com.Entity" xmlns:ns3="http://example.com" xmlns:ns2="http://example.com.PrimaryKey">
         <infos>
            <entries>
               <key>apiKey</key>
               <value>key</value>
            </entries>
            <entries>
               <key>apiSecret</key>
               <value>secret</value>
            </entries>
         </infos>
         <type>source</type>
      </ns9:HeaderInfo>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <ns1:insertContact xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/">
         <password xmlns:ns2="http://example.com.PrimaryKey" xmlns:ns3="http://example.com" xmlns:ns4="http://example.com.Entity" xmlns:ns5="http://example.com.Utilities" xmlns:ns6="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/FileServiceWcfServiceLibrary.Domain" xmlns:ns7="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:ns8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:ns9="http://example.com/">password</password>
         <contact xmlns:ns2="http://example.com.PrimaryKey" xmlns:ns3="http://example.com" xmlns:ns4="http://example.com.Entity" xmlns:ns5="http://example.com.Utilities" xmlns:ns6="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/FileServiceWcfServiceLibrary.Domain" xmlns:ns7="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:ns8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:ns9="http://example.com/">
            <ns3:Address1_City xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:Address1_Line1 xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:Address1_PostalCode xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:Address1_StateOrProvince xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:Address1_Telephone1 xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:Birthdate xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:Country>
               <ns2:CountryCode>GB</ns2:CountryCode>
            </ns3:Country>
            <ns3:CreatedBy xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:CreatedOn xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:EmailAddress1>email@example.com</ns3:EmailAddress1>
            <ns3:FacebookId xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:FirstName>FirstName</ns3:FirstName>
            <ns3:FiscalCode xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:GooglePlusId xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:Id xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:IdBadgeminton xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:isM xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:isMotoM xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:IsPir xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:IsCar xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:isF1 xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:isMoto></ns3:isMoto>
            <ns3:isTyre xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:LangCode>en</ns3:LangCode>
            <ns3:LastName>LastName</ns3:LastName>
            <ns3:MobilePhone xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:ModifiedBy xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:ModifiedOn xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:NickName xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:Privacy>true</ns3:Privacy>
            <ns3:PrivacyGroup>false</ns3:PrivacyGroup>
            <ns3:PrivacyThird>false</ns3:PrivacyThird>
            <ns3:Source>SoapUI</ns3:Source>
            <ns3:StateCode xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:StatusCode xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:SubscriptionConfirmed xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns3:TwitterId xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
         </contact>
      </ns1:insertContact>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have no idea on how to do this schema, I've just understood how to create Headers, but nothing more at all. This I what I've tried so far:

```
$soapClient=new SoapClient(WSDL_URI,array(
        'trace' => true,
        'login' => 'user',
        'password' => 'password'
    ));
    $soapHeader=new SOAPHeader(API_NAMESPACE,'HeaderInfo',array(
        'infos' => array(
            'entries' => array(
                'key' => 'apiKey',
                'value' => APIKEY
            ),
            'entries' => array(
                'key' => 'apiSecret',
                'value' => APISECRET
            )
        ),
        'type' => 'source'
    ));
    $soapClient->__setSoapHeaders($soapHeader);
    $soapContactParams=[];
    $soapContactParams[]=new SoapVar('email@example.com',XSD_STRING,null,null,'EmailAddress1');
    $soapContactParams[]=new SoapVar('source',XSD_STRING,null,null,'Source');
    $soapContact=new SoapVar($soapContactParams,SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,null,null,'contact');
    $soapClient->insertContact(password,$soapContact);
```

Which is giving me this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Fault occurred while processing. in /var/www/example.com/example.com/test/index.php:34 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/example.com/example.com/test/index.php(34): SoapClient->__call('insertContact', Array) #1 /var/www/example.com/example.com/test/index.php(34): SoapClient->insertContact('password', Object(SoapVar)) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/example.com/example.com/test/index.php on line 34
```

I'm actually quite new to `PHP SOAP`, and let me say it, I don't like it at all. I don't even know if I'm building a well-formatted XML because I can't print it.

## Last Edit

I've canceled all the edits I've done before because they were all pointing to the same direction: nothing works at all.

So I've tried copying their example `XML`, but it doens't work. I think I will stop trying understanding `SOAP`, at least for `PHP`, because it's quite annoying, boring, and not well documented at all. ( why do I need to hardcode XML? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 weeks of intense work, I've found the problem.

I'm using WSDL, remember it, WSDL has been a double-edged weapon for me. As read in the docs, using it will let `SoapClient` automatically find the endpoint, all the functions and all the types which `SoapServer` requires, and that's good.

My problem was the endpoint, and I really,really suggest you to double check that, because mine wasn't right. I had to force it because I was getting only `unable to connect to host` errors, and nothing more.

#### So this is my code that made it work. Finally

```
class SoapClientDebug extends SoapClient {
    function __construct($wsdl, $options) {
        parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
        $this->server = new SoapServer($wsdl, $options);
    }
    public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0) {
        $location=THE_CORRECT_ENDPOINT;
        return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0);
    }
}
```

Trust me, check it. I've lost 3 weeks of work by searching for a problem, when the problem was actually simple.

Anyway, I still hate SOAP on PHP :)